# counting distinct and repetitions mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, count, unique

i would like to ask how to count distinct and repetitions in mysql

for example table looks like this

main_table

```
id      product_id   purchaser_id  
1       1               1
2       1               1          
3       1               1 
4       1               2
 5      1               2
 6      1               3
 7      2               1  
 8      2              2 
9       2             2
10      2             2
11       2            2
12      2             3
13       2           3
14      2            3
15     2             3
16     2             4
17      2            4
```

using this code

```
SELECT a.product_id,a.purchaser_id, 
       COUNT(DISTINCT a.purchaser_id) AS unique_purchasers, 
       COALESCE(c.totalCount,0) AS repeat_purchasers 
FROM main_table a 
    LEFT JOIN ( SELECT product_id, COUNT(totalCOunt) totalCount 
                FROM ( SELECT product_id, purchaser_id, COUNT(*) totalCOunt 
                        FROM main_table GROUP BY product_id, purchaser_id 
                        HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 ) s GROUP BY product_id ) c 
            ON a.product_id = c.product_id GROUP BY product_id, purchaser_id
```

result is

```
product_id  purchaser_id    unique_purchasers   repeat_purchasers   
1   1   1   2
1   2   1   2
1   3   1   2
2   1   1   3
2   2   1   3
2   3   1   3
2   4   1   3
```

but result should be like this(meaning if no repeat then 0)

```
product_id  purchaser_id    unique_purchasers   repeat_purchasers   
1   1   1   2
1   2   1   1
1   3   1   0
2   1   1   0
2   2   1   3
2   3   1   3
2   4   1   1
```

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT a.product_id,a.purchaser_id, 
       COUNT(DISTINCT a.purchaser_id) AS unique_purchasers,
       c.totalcount as repeat_purchasers
FROM main_table a 
INNER JOIN (SELECT product_id, purchaser_id, COUNT(*)-1 totalCOunt 
                        FROM main_table GROUP BY product_id, purchaser_id 
                ) C ON C.product_id=a.product_id AND a.purchaser_id=C.purchaser_id             
GROUP BY product_id, purchaser_id
```

Result:

```
PRODUCT_ID  PURCHASER_ID    UNIQUE_PURCHASERS   REPEAT_PURCHASERS
1           1               1                   2
1           2               1                   1
1           3               1                   0
2           1               1                   0
2           2               1                   3
2           3               1                   3
2           4               1                   1
```

See result in [**Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cf353/31).

Comment: is there really need of the unique_purchasers column?

Comment: @swapnil7: Ask OP. I just provided what he is looking for. In my opinion, in this case, `COUNT(DISTINCT col)` always return 1.

Comment: you are right , but it seems there is no need to add that column in the result

Comment: @swapnil7: I told you, I am just giving a hand to OP to get what he is looking for. I suppose, he needs that kind of output.